# Cauchy integral, why is it equal zero?

Tags: complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have the following Cauchy integral evaluated only in $\mid\zeta\mid\leq 1$,

$$\int_\gamma t\cdot\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}\frac{dt}{t}$$

which has one (?) pole at $\zeta$.

$\gamma$ is circle of unit radius in the plane of complex variables $\zeta$

$\zeta$ is arbitrary points in the plane of complex variables

$t$ are points located in the unit circle $\gamma$

Thus, the solution can be evaluated by,

$$\int_\gamma t\cdot\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_\gamma \frac{t}{t}\cdot\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} dt=2\pi i(\zeta+\zeta)=4\pi i\zeta$$

Now, suppose I want to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}\frac{dt}{t}$$

is it correct to say that the integral also has one (?) pole at $\zeta$? and hence,

$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_\gamma \frac{1}{t^2}\cdot\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}dt = 2\pi i\left(\frac{\zeta+\zeta}{\zeta^2}\right)=2\pi i\left(\frac{2}{\zeta}\right)=\frac{4\pi i}{\zeta}$$

The reason I am asking is that the solution says the result of the last integral equals zero instead of $\frac{4\pi i}{\zeta}$.

Which one is correct?

Can anyone show me the correct solution please?

Comment: What is $\gamma$?

Comment: Hi @JoséCarlosSantos, I have edited the post to answer your question

Comment: You have added two poles to the integrand.

Comment: @copper.hat, what is the correct solution then?

Comment: Your first evaluation is only valid if $|\zeta|<1$.

Comment: How can $\zeta$ be an arbitrary point? If $\zeta$ is outside the unit circle then the first integral is zero.

Comment: @copper.hat, correct. It will be zero if the function is analytic.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Yes, true. The integral is evaluated only for $\mid \zeta \mid\leq 1$

Comment: Then they cannot be arbitrary points.

Comment: @BeeTiau Perhaps you should state that in the question then?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thans, I have corrected and mentioned it in the post. I hope it clarifies the question.

Comment: You might want to look at the Laurent expansion approach so you understand why adding the double pole changes the result significantly. Residues hide the intuition and are often taught in a rote fashion.

Comment: @copper.hat, I see your explanation below also clarifies the result should equal zero.

Comment: More importantly, it should show you **why** adding the double pole result in a zero result.

Comment: @copper.hat, yes, you are definitely correct. I agree with you.

Comment: My job is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the $t$ out for $\frac{1}{t}$ changed the integral quite a bit

$$\oint_\gamma\frac{1}{t^2}\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}dt=2\pi i\sum_{j=1}^n\operatorname{Res}(f(t),t_j)$$

Now there's a pole at $t=\zeta$ (order $1$) and $t=0$ (order $2$), so

$$\operatorname{Res}(f,0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{d}{dt}\left(t^2\frac{1}{t^2}\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}\right)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0}\left(\frac{-2\zeta}{(t-\zeta)^2}\right)=-\frac{2}{\zeta}$$

Assuming that $\gamma$ encloses both $t=0$ and $t=\zeta$ then,

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\operatorname{Res}(f(t),t_j)=\frac{2}{\zeta}-\frac{2}{\zeta}=0$$

And the integral is $0$

Comment: So, my derivation is *not* correct because it ignores the fact that the integral is actually has two poles, instead of 1. Is it correct?

Comment: @BeeTiau: You might have inferred that from my first comment.

Comment: for the sake of completeness of the correct answer, should I add that the residue for the pole at $\zeta$ is $$Res(f,\zeta) = \frac{2}{\zeta}$$

Comment: Yes, your derivation did not account for the pole at $t=0$. You did correctly calculate the residue at $t=\zeta$, which is why I did not include it. Looking at it now though, it was worth mentioning for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $|z| > |\zeta|$ we have ${1 \over z -\zeta} = { 1 \over z} (1+ {\zeta \over z} + {\zeta^2 \over z^2} + \cdots)$.

Then the coefficient of ${ 1\over z}$ in the Laurent expansion of $z \mapsto {z+\zeta \over z -\zeta}$ can be read off as $ 2 \zeta$ (one from the $z$ in $z+\zeta$ and one from the $\zeta$ in $z+\zeta$).

Similarly, for $z \mapsto {1 \over z^2}{z+\zeta \over z -\zeta}$, we can see that the Laurent series expansion has only
 terms of ${1 \over z^2}$ and higher, hence the integral is zero.

Answer (score 0):

By the residue theorem the value of 
$$ \oint \frac{z+a}{z-a}\,dz =2a\oint\frac{dz}{z-a}$$
depends on $a$ falling *inside* or *outside* the (simple) integration contour. If $a$ lies *on* the integration contour such integral is non-convergent in the usual sense, but its principal value is just the average of the values computed by considering it inside/outside the given contour.